# start-stop-daemon and Valgrind

Tags: valgrind, start-stop-daemon

I use start-stop-daemon to start up programs and would like to use it together with Valgrind.

This is how I use start-stop-daemon:

```
start-stop-daemon --start --background --exec ${BINPATH}/myPgm -- myPgm
```

This is how I use Valgrind on a standalone application (junk):

```
valgrind --tool=memcheck --leak-check=yes ./junk
```

and that works.

I would want to do something like:

```
start-stop-daemon --start --background --exec valgrind --tool=memcheck --leak-check=yes --log-file=/usr/magnus/logFile ${BINPATH}/myPgm -- myPgm
```

It seems start-stop-daemon accepts valgrind (if I only have valgrind without it's flags `--tool=memcheck --leak-check=yes --log-file=/usr/magnus/logFile` it seem to be accepted)
but start-stop-daemon won't accept it.

I get start-stop-daemon: `unrecognized option '--tool=memcheck'` for the valgrind flags.

Does anybody know how this can be done?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The "--" in there is used to separate start-stop-daemon's arguments from the ones passed to your executable.  So, the myPgm you have after "--" is actually supplied as an argument to your myPgm executable.  I think it's extraneous in your first example.

You need to use "--" to split valgrind's args out, like this:

```
start-stop-daemon --start --background --exec valgrind -- --tool=memcheck --leak-check=yes --log-file=/usr/magnus/logFile ${BINPATH}/myPgm
```